# How to use a Typealias or Closure to define a constant with a parameter for name in swift?

Tags: swift

In Objective C I used to define constants using #defines as a way to quickly and explicitly define strings for localization and keep the code a little more clean.

For example:

```
#define DefineStringKey(x) static NSString *const x = @#x
```

This would let me define in constants that are named the same as the string 
so `DefineStringKey(@"IntroTitle");` would create a constnat called *IntroTitle* with the value *IntroTitle* that I could refer to within my code (autocomplete and all).

I had an idea that I might be able to do the same in Swift but I can't seem to get the syntax correct using typealias or closures.

Type Alias

```
typealias DefineStringKey:(x:String) = let x:String = x
```

Closure

```
let DefineStringKey:(String) = (String) -> () {
   (x:String) in
   let x:(String) = x
}
```

Clearly both examples I gave are incorrect. Is this something I can do in Swift via another method or is my syntax just off.

*Edited to add a use case.*

Comment: `#define` is a pre-compiler directive. All of your Swift attempt are runtime. Why not show a clear example of how you intend to use these constants. Then someone may be able to offer a good solution.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. What is `key` ? What do you want ? If it's a simple costant value, why you need `typealias` ? Anyway, that's not how `closures` works

Comment: @rmaddy Added an example per your suggestion.

Comment: @Andrew21111 'key' in this context is the stringName and value I would like to set. I changed the post to reflect what I wrote in the Objective C example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, **Swift** does not have macros, so you cannot define a constant (or variable) without writing out `let myConstant = ...`. What you can do is use a closure to define a constant that you can use within the closure's inner scope:

```swift
func defineStringKey(_ key: String, handler: (String) -> Void) {
    handler(key)
}
```

Put that anywhere in the global scope, and you can use it like this:

```swift
defineStringKey("IntroTitle") { IntroTitle in
    print(IntroTitle)
}
```

That prints out `IntroTitle`. This isn't very useful though, and I do not recommend using it. In swift, you have to explicitly type out your variable definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I will type everything out explicitly to keep same functionality in my new version.